# Permit in a stablecoin

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, erc-20

I am trying around and writing a kind of new stablecoin code. How should a permit function look like so it is correctly embedded and secure against any fraudulent usages?

Answer (score 1):

The whole permit EIP is still in draft phase, but OpenZeppelin has an implementation for it. So you should probably just use that: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol

Comment: Thanks - and could you give me a hint how this could be added to a contract in a correct way without any risks. Just import the sole fil and invoke it with the constructor?

Comment: Here's my recent project where I use it: https://github.com/membranefi/euro-stablecoin/blob/02bb9c7d247c218d090ae54ffac19df919ab11c8/contracts/EUROStablecoin.sol#L130